# Predictions using time dependent covariates in survival model

Tags: r

Simple question, how do you specify time dependent covariates in the data.frame supplied to `newdata` when looking to make predictions?

In other words, I fit a model with time dependent covariates:

```
cfit <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~ treat + sex + age +
            inherit + cluster(id), data=cgd)
```

Now I'd like to create a prediction for a patient, but using updated data from that patient. In other words, what is their survival probability, given that we observed changes in certain covariates within that certain time intervals?

I can predict survival for a *new* patient, as follows:

```
survfit(cfit, newdata=data.frame(treat = "placebo", age = 12, sex ="male", inherit = "X-linked"))$surv
```

But this does not allow me to update predictions as time passes from the start of observation for that patient, allowing for the incorporation of updated covariates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is detailed in the 4th paragraph of the details section of the help page `?survfit.coxph`.  Basically you need an `id` column that shows which rows belong to the same person, then for each row you need the beginning time, the ending time, and the values of the covariates during that time period.  Each time period for the individual being predicted will have its own row in `newdata` (so the time periods should not overlap).

Comment: Great,  now how does one interpret the output from the prediction,  as it returns a vector for each row in the newdata frame.

Comment: @BenRollert, I suggest plotting the result.

Comment: Yes, if I plot the result I get two survival curves, but for one patient. What is the interpretation? Perhaps this a worth a new question.

Comment: @BenRollert, it would help to provide a reproducible example with a small sample dataset and your `newdata` for prediction and the code that you have used so far.  That would make it easier for us to explain what you are seeing or modify your code to give what you want.  You could add this to this question, or start a new question.

Comment: Hi Ben, I have the same issue, including "returning a vector for each row in the newdata frame". You need to do what Greg Snow said, but also include the argument "id = XXX", where XXX is the name is the variable that identifies each patient.

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example in R to my comment above:

```
## Install package that has a dataset with data applicable for this problem
install.packages("ipw")
library(ipw)

## Load data
head(haartdat,n=100)

## Fit model, with time varying covariate cd4.sqrt
model.2 <- coxph(Surv(tstart, fuptime, event) ~ sex + age + cd4.sqrt + cluster(patient), data = haartdat)

## Create dataframe of variables (one row)
covs <- data.frame(age = 25,sex = 1,cd4.sqrt = 24)
covs
## Get survival probabilities for these variables at baseline
summary(survfit(model.2, newdata = covs, type = "aalen"))


## Now create two 'newdata' sets of covariates, for time points up to 1900
## covs.2 the data is same at all 20 time points
covs.2 <- cbind(rep(1,20),rbind(covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs))
colnames(covs.2)[1] <- "patient"
covs.2 <- data.frame(covs.2)
covs.2$tstart <- seq(-100,1800,100)
covs.2$fuptime <- seq(0,1900,100)
covs.2$event <- rep(0,20)

## covs.3 has varying cd4.sqrt
covs.3 <- cbind(rep(2,20),rbind(covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs,covs))
colnames(covs.3)[1] <- "patient"
covs.3 <- data.frame(covs.3)
covs.3$tstart <- seq(-100,1800,100)
covs.3$fuptime <- seq(0,1900,100)
covs.3$event <- rep(0,20)
covs.3$cd4.sqrt <- seq(20.25,25,0.25)

## Combine into one dataset
covs.4 <- rbind(covs.2,covs.3)
covs.4

## Create survival probabilities, with the id = argument
summary(survfit(model.2, newdata = covs.4, type = "aalen", id = patient))
```